# Does converting polygon to raster generate more accurate results from the Zonal Statistics in Arcgis 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, polygon, arcgis-10.2, zonal-statistics

I have heard the following for Arcgis 9.1 and wonder whether it is still an issue in Arcgis 10.2.  If so, should I convert the polygon into raster before dissolve or convert the dissolved polygon directly?

http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/19184